# git-svn no longer creates branches for subversion tags

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm using [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) to manage code locally in Git that is stored centrally in Subversion. The Subversion repository uses the standard layout of "trunks/branches/tags"; when I created the git repository I used the "--stdlayout" argument.

Whenever I would run `git svn rebase`, Git would correctly create branches whenever Subversion tags were created:

[image: Annotated tag]

However, recently Git stop creating these branches, and now they simply appear as:

[image: Missing annotated tag]

How can I restore the original behavior of Git creating a branch whenever there is a new Subversion tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the command `git svn rebase` will only fetch "the SVN parent of the current HEAD" as explained in the [git-svn documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html). To fetch all revisions including branches, you can use `git svn rebase --fetch-all`, or use `git svn fetch` and then rebase in a separate step.